# Free registration title in website

Tags: grammar

Which of the below sentences is correct?

`Free join to Google`

Or

`Join Free for Google`

Or

`Join for free Google`

I prefer to use the `Free` word at the beginning of the sentence.

**Note:** Google is just an example.

Comment: You need to provide some context to explain what this title is supposed to mean. None of those phrases make much sense (especially as Google is already free).

Comment: The most normally used formulation would be *join Google for free.* The only normal sounding formulation I can think of that puts *free* at the start of the sentence is something like: *It's free! Join Google.* But that sounds like a sales pitch—and I should note that nobody thinks it costs money to join Google anyway, so it's strange to mention that it's free in the first place.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the comments. `Google` here is an example.

Comment: Nowadays it is commonly expected that things on the Internet are free, or at least have a free trial period. Thus "free" can (and should) be completely dropped, making it "Join <my cool website>" or simply "Sign Up"

Comment: @VahidNajafi If it's just an example, then what are you actually asking that our comments and answers aren't addressing?

Comment: @JasonBassford All your sentences are correct. I was wondering if there is a way to start with `Free` word at the beginning. Btw, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange. The most common way of saying it would be "Join Google for free." If you want to put free at the beginning you can say "It's free to join Google." However, the meaning changes in this case. The first sentence is a command (it tells the reader to join), while the second sentence is just a statement (it gives the reader information).

Comment: Thank you. `Google` here is an example.

Comment: @VahidNajafi Remember to mark my answer as the solution if you feel that it's adequate :)